# htaccess, site and staging in subdirectories

Tags: htaccess, directory, mod-rewrite, staging

I have the following task and as it is a little different from most setups, I couldn't find any hints that solved my problem.

WordPress for the live site was installed into a subfolder `/wp1`, the `.htaccess` directives are a rewrite to www and https followed by the usual WP directives:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# rewrite any request to the certified domain to use www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# rewrite to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and `index.php` in the root loads the necessary `wp1/wp-blog-header.php`.

Now I need to set up a staging environment in `/wp2` with `wp2` as the subdomain. The subdomain does not have a SSL-certificate (but I could easily get one). I tried several modifications in order to redirect the subdomain to the staging site without https, but all I got so far was errors.

Although I am not that familiar with `.htaccess`, I think the first problem is the wildcard redirect to www. The second obstacle is the redirect to https. I need them both for production.

Is there a way to skip those rules in case the subdomain is addressed?

Or in general, how would you go about that?

Comment: "WordPress for the live site was installed into a subfolder `/wp1`, the htaccess directives are the usual" - Although the "problem" with the "usual" directives in `.htaccess` is that those directives are intended to work with a site installed in the root, not a subdirectory. "...and index.php in root loads the necessary `wp1/wp-blog-header.php`" - Why are you doing it that way?

Comment: Actually I don't know, it has been done that way in 2011, because there was another cms already installed in root. It is method 2 given in the Codex: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). I'm not sure what you are hinting at?

Comment: Can you not configure your `wp2` subdomain to point directly to the `/wp2` subdirectory, instead of the document root of the main site (which I assume is where it is pointing to now)? Then you wouldn't have to do anything. (I assume `/wp1` features in the URLs for the live site?)

Comment: Concerning the subdomain: not by myself, thanks for the hint. Concerning the URLs: the subdirectory isn't part of them.

Comment: I decided the problem is solved by not using a subdomain, not having to poke around in the htaccess of a live site. Putting "ErrorDocument 401 default" into root htaccess solved the problem of 401 errors showing up and I hope I can continue to work, now. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You didn't mention 401 _responses_ in your question? Although `ErrorDocument 401 default` wouldn't "solve" the 401 response, it would just prevent a previously defined "custom" response being served. I'll throw down an answer shortly regarding your original question, using a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `/wp2` subdirectory containing the staging site has its own WordPress `.htaccess` file (with the standard WordPress front-controller, see below). Then the `.htaccess` in the document root should contain something like the the following, above any existing directives, to rewrite all requests to the `wp2` subdomain to the `/wp2` subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wp2)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

Then, the "standard" WordPress front-controller would be in the `/wp2/.htaccess` file (this also prevents a potential rewrite loop):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note that I have removed the `RewriteBase` directive entirely and removed the slash prefix on the last `RewriteRule` *substitution*. This is so that it will load `index.php` from `/wp2/index.php` and not the document root. (Which is really how I would expect the main site in `/wp1` to be configured.)